# Using the checked binding in knockout with a list of checkboxes checks all the checkboxes

Tags: knockout.js

I have a problem when binding a list of complex values (id/ 
description) to a list of checkboxes.

The problem is that I need not just the id or the description, but 
both.

When I bind using the Checked binding, all the checkboxes in my list 
are checked when I click one item.

This is part of something bigger, and the reason I want the object and 
not just the id is that the complex type in turn will have a list 
which I want to bind to another list of checkboxes.

Here is a fiddle that produces the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/M8KFd/1

Thankful for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I track the state of each item individually, then get the selected items using a [dependent observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/dependentObservables.html) something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dBGdP/1/)

Comment: Awesomeness! My list is serialized data from the backend, but I ended up looping the initial array, slapping on the selected property: http://jsfiddle.net/M8KFd/2/
BTW, You should consider using `ko.utils.arrayFilter` instead of `$.grep` to avoid mixing dependencies in the code.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution, is to fake the checkbox with css, then with knockout just call a method which will pass the whole item to the viewmodel:

```
  <li data-bind="click: $parent.setCompany">
        <span data-bind="text: CompanyName"></span>,
        <span data-bind="text: RegAddress_PostTown"></span>
   </li>
```

Of course this does not work for all scenarios as per Richard Friend's answer.