# Javascript Equivalent to C# LINQ Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Following this question here :

> [Using the checked binding in knockout with a list of checkboxes checks all the checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180744/using-the-checked-binding-in-knockout-with-a-list-of-checkboxes-checks-all-the-c)

I've created some checkboxes using knockout that allow selection from an array.
working fiddle taken from above post:

> http://jsfiddle.net/NsCXJ/

Is there a simple way of creating an array of just the fruit's ID's?

I'm more at home with C# where I would do something along the lines of `selectedFruits.select(fruit=>fruit.id);`

Is there some method/ready made function for doing something similar with javascript/jquery?  Or would the simplest option be to loop through the list and create a second array?
I intend to post the array back to the server in JSON so am trying to minimize the data sent.

Answer (score 292, accepted):

Yes, [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) does the same thing.

```
//array.map:
var ids = this.fruits.map(function(v){
    return v.Id;
});

//jQuery.map:
var ids2 = $.map(this.fruits, function (v){
    return v.Id;
});

console.log(ids, ids2);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NsCXJ/1/

Since array.map isn't supported in older browsers, I suggest that you stick with the jQuery method.

If you prefer the other one for some reason you could always add a polyfill for old browser support.

You can always add custom methods to the array prototype as well:

```
Array.prototype.select = function(expr){
    var arr = this;
    //do custom stuff
    return arr.map(expr); //or $.map(expr);
};

var ids = this.fruits.select(function(v){
    return v.Id;
});
```

---

An extended version that uses the function constructor if you pass a string. Something to play around with perhaps:

```
Array.prototype.select = function(expr){
    var arr = this;

    switch(typeof expr){

        case 'function':
            return $.map(arr, expr);
            break;

        case 'string':

            try{

                var func = new Function(expr.split('.')[0], 
                                       'return ' + expr + ';');
                return $.map(arr, func);

            }catch(e){

                return null;
            }

            break;

        default:
            throw new ReferenceError('expr not defined or not supported');
            break;
    }

};

console.log(fruits.select('x.Id'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aL85j/

**Update:**

Since this has become such a popular answer, I'm adding similar my `where()` +  `firstOrDefault()`. These could also be used with the string based function constructor approach (which is the fastest), but here is another approach using an object literal as filter:

```
Array.prototype.where = function (filter) {

    var collection = this;

    switch(typeof filter) { 

        case 'function': 
            return $.grep(collection, filter); 

        case 'object':
            for(var property in filter) {
              if(!filter.hasOwnProperty(property)) 
                  continue; // ignore inherited properties

              collection = $.grep(collection, function (item) {
                  return item[property] === filter[property];
              });
            }
            return collection.slice(0); // copy the array 
                                      // (in case of empty object filter)

        default: 
            throw new TypeError('func must be either a' +
                'function or an object of properties and values to filter by'); 
    }
};


Array.prototype.firstOrDefault = function(func){
    return this.where(func)[0] || null;
};
```

Usage:

```
var persons = [{ name: 'foo', age: 1 }, { name: 'bar', age: 2 }];

// returns an array with one element:
var result1 = persons.where({ age: 1, name: 'foo' });

// returns the first matching item in the array, or null if no match
var result2 = persons.firstOrDefault({ age: 1, name: 'foo' });
```

Here is a [jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/3-kinds-of-grepping) to compare the function constructor vs object literal speed. If you decide to use the former, keep in mind to quote strings correctly.

My personal preference is to use the object literal based solutions when filtering 1-2 properties, and pass a callback function for more complex filtering.

I'll end this with 2 general tips when adding methods to native object prototypes:

1. Check for occurrence of existing methods before overwriting e.g.:

   `if(!Array.prototype.where) {
       Array.prototype.where = ...`
2. If you don't need to support IE8 and below, define the methods using [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to make them non-enumerable. If someone used `for..in` on an array (which is wrong in the first place)
   they will iterate enumerable properties as well. Just a heads up.

Comment: @ChrisNevill I added a string version as well in case you're intrested

Comment: @MUlferts Good catch, updated :). Nowadays I would suggest using lodash for these kinds of tasks. They expose the same interface as the code above

Comment: To support knockout observables: `return typeof item[property] === 'function' ? item[property]() === filter[property] : item[property] === filter[property];`

Comment: @LinusCaldwell It's been a long time since I used knockout, but what about something like `return ko.unwrap(item[property]) === filter[property]`?

Comment: Well, I mentioned knockout, but of course this would cover all properties which are functions without required parameters. Besides, why would one break the generic style of your beautiful code?

Comment: “map” is not the same as “select” in C#. Map returns a new array, Select returns an enumerable (delayed until iteration).

Answer (score 35):

I know it is a late answer but it was useful to me! Just to complete, using the `$.grep` function you can emulate the linq `where()`.

Linq:

```
var maleNames = people
.Where(p => p.Sex == "M")
.Select(p => p.Name)
```

Javascript:

```
// replace where  with $.grep
//         select with $.map
var maleNames = $.grep(people, function (p) { return p.Sex == 'M'; })
            .map(function (p) { return p.Name; });
```

Comment: that's what i want..but what is more good in between your answer and     Enumerable.From(selectedFruits).Select(function (fruit) { return fruit.id;  });

Comment: This is a great idea! You can do something like: var list = $.grep(row.children, function(c) { return c.className.includes("MyClass"); });  if (list .length > 0) { } ---> then you found one. ---> this will find an html element with class = "MyClass" .includes("findtext") is like .Contains("findtext").

Comment: Here is a better way to find an element with a specific class name in it: var rows = $('#MyId table tr'); var list = $.grep(rows[0].children, function (c) { return c.classList.contains("MyClass"); }); 
if (list.length > 0) { }

Answer (score 20):

The ES6 way:

```
let people = [{firstName:'Alice',lastName:'Cooper'},{firstName:'Bob',age:'Dylan'}];
let names = Array.from(people, p => p.firstName);
for (let name of names) {
  console.log(name);
}
```

also at: https://jsfiddle.net/52dpucey/

Comment: Much appreciated. I'm just getting into ES6 so this could be handy!

Answer (score 18):

Since you're using knockout, you should consider using the knockout utility function `arrayMap()` and it's other array utility functions.

Here's a listing of array utility functions and their equivalent LINQ methods:

```
arrayFilter() -> Where()
arrayFirst() -> First()
arrayForEach() -> (no direct equivalent)
arrayGetDistictValues() -> Distinct()
arrayIndexOf() -> IndexOf()
arrayMap() -> Select()
arrayPushAll() -> (no direct equivalent)
arrayRemoveItem() -> (no direct equivalent)
compareArrays() -> (no direct equivalent)
```

So what you could do in your example is this:

```
var mapped = ko.utils.arrayMap(selectedFruits, function (fruit) {
    return fruit.id;
});
```

If you want a LINQ like interface in javascript, you could use a library such as [linq.js](https://github.com/mihaifm/linq) which offers a nice interface to many of the LINQ methods.

```
var mapped = Enumerable.from(selectedFruits)
    .select("$.id") // shorthand for `x => x.id`
    .toArray();
```

Answer (score 11):

You can also try [**`linq.js`**](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/)

In [**`linq.js`**](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/) your

```
selectedFruits.select(fruit=>fruit.id);
```

will be

```
Enumerable.From(selectedFruits).Select(function (fruit) { return fruit.id;  });
```

Answer (score 4):

The most similar C# `Select` analogue would be a `map` function.
Just use:

```js
var ids = selectedFruits.map(fruit => fruit.id);
```

to select all ids from `selectedFruits` array.

It doesn't require any external dependencies, just pure JavaScript. You can find `map` documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 3):

I have build a Linq library for TypeScript under [TsLinq.codeplex.com](http://TsLinq.codeplex.com) that you can use for plain javascript too. That library is 2-3 times faster than Linq.js and contains unit tests for all Linq methods. Maybe you could review that one.

Comment: This link needs updating

Comment: I haven’t maintained it since the first version, and not used it since ages anymore. So if it’s gone, it’s gone :)

Comment: That's Fair enough 

Answer (score 0):

Take a peek at [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) which provides many linq like functions. In the example you give you would use the map function.

Comment: If someone wants to know how they compare I made blog post which explains difference between more than 15 most popular LINQ/underscore.js functions: https://www.vladopandzic.com/javascript/comparing-underscore-js-with-linq/