# Javascript: select array into new array (like C# Select)

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, mapping

In C# if I had a list for example of 3 ints `[1,2,3]`, I could trasform that list into another with `.Select` in following way `[1,2,3].Select(e => new { Id = e, Name = $"name:{e}")`, which would return new array with 3 objects.

how can I get the same result in js without using for loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Equivalent to C# LINQ Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936774/javascript-equivalent-to-c-sharp-linq-select)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `map` function like this:

```
var array = [1,2,3]

var result = array.map(e => ({id: e, name: `name:${e}`}))
console.log(result)
```

It returns the following result:

```
[ { id: 1, name: 'name:1' }, 
  { id: 2, name: 'name:2' }, 
  { id: 3, name: 'name:3' } ]
```

Here is the `map` function docs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is called `map`(example with integers, but you can map into objects too):

```
const array1 = [1, 4, 9, 16];
const map1 = array1.map(x => x * 2);
console.log(map1);
// expected output: Array [2, 8, 18, 32]
```